# Out of date error message on tortoise

Tags: tortoisesvn, checksum

I am trying to commit a file that is out of date. I tried cleaning the directory and nothing is working... the most recent file on my local machine is the one i know i want to use.. what is the standard way of overriding the conflict... should i just delete and re-add or is there another way "resource is out of date try updating"

UPDATE BASED ON ADVICE TO UPDATE*** I am getting a "checksum mismatch" error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to update your local copy of the file.  Right click and click update.

Any changes that have been made since your last update will be merged with your current copy.  You can then right click on the file and select resolve conflicts.

If you want to ignore any changes that were made and just use your local copy, the easiest way is to copy your file to another location, update, then overwrite the file with your local copy.  However you usually will want to let Tortoise handle merging any changes for you.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try an update? You need to update your local copy to the current version in the repository. Right click, and select 'update'.

Comment: yeah i tried that but for some reason that one file is failing even on the update

Comment: An update usually sorts out the commit issue. Works for me every time

Comment: I am getting a "checksum mismatch"

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, it turns out that there are hidden folders containing data that tortoise uses to maintain some record of changes that have been made. If the data in your local folder does not match the data in the server, then you get a whole lot of errors that make very little sense.

To fix this, Right click on your folder and click "SVN Update".

IF you still get an error, open your local folder in explorer, enable viewing of system files and hidden files, and look to see if there is more than 1 hidden .svn folder inside your local directory.

In my case, I had accidentally copied another .svn folder into my local directory. This extra .svn folder was causing the update errors. There should only be 1 .svn folder in your root directory.

Delete the extra .svn folder (usually only the local root folder has the .svn folder) and try updating again.

Tortoise should update your local copy and then you can commit your changes without a problem.